# Show boundedness of sets in equality form?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $D=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid x^Tx=c^Tx\}$, show that it is bounded?
I tried to show that

$p,q \in D \rightarrow \|p-q\| \leq M$:

$\|p-q\|^2=\|p\|^2+\|q\|^2-2p^Tq \leq \|p\|\|c\|+\|q\|\|c\|+2\|p\|\|q\|$

I do not know how to proceed or my understanding of definition of the boundedness is correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

First: work with the actual definition of boundedness.  You're trying to show finite diameter, but boundedness is easier to deal with.  Boundedness means that there exists $M$ such that $x\in D$ implies $\|x\|\leq M$.

Second: Note that $x^Tx=\|x\|^2$, while
$$
c^Tx=\|c\|\cdot\|x\|\cdot\cos\theta,
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle formed by $c$ and $x$.

Comment: Could you finish the proof? Can I write $\|x\|^2=c^Tx \leq \|c\|_*\|x\| \rightarrow \|x\| \leq \|c\|_* $ where $\|c\|_* $ is the dual norm to conclude that the set is bounded?

Comment: You are making this complicated.  I'm not sure where a dual norm is coming from?  Just note that for any non-zero vector in $D$, we have $\|x\|\leq\|c\|$ (and that the zero vector trivially satisfies this as well), and you're done.